# SP2010 - Resource Reservation - allow only one selection

Tags: calendar

Situation:
Attempting to create a conference room calendar.
I've created a calendar and enabled resource reservation.
A 'new event' form allows users to select resources (rooms in this case).

Question:
Is it possible to have it so users can only select one resource?  Or even do some type of data validation?

Unlike most lookup columns, I can't seem to modify the column setting to allow only single choice.

Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement as yours. I'll work on it and get back here for what I'll have come up with

Answer (score 1):

After some deep investigation, I can confirm the following:

- the resource field (`SPFieldFacilities`) is a special type of `SPFieldLookup` (it derives from it) and the `AllowMultipleValues` flag is internally set to true and cannot be modified through the UI. It could be modified via PowerShell, and it would behave like a normal lookup field, but the Check Double Booking feature wouldn't work anymore.
- if you only want to force it to allow only one selection (even though I believe that's not the full story and what you really need is to forcibly set it to some value...at least, this is my scenario, but I digress -I'll blog about this sooner or later), then the solution involves a hack as dirty as hell, which is *hijacking* one of the javascript function that takes care of handling the two select list boxes events (I'm referring to the two boxes next to the Add/Remove buttons)

The function to overwrite is `GipAddSelectedItems` and the following is the amended code you'll want to insert in the NewForm.aspx page, preferably inside the content place holder with ID `PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass`:

```
GipAddSelectedItems = function (master)
{ULSc04:;

// HACK *********************************************************
// remove all the selections from the box on the right
for(var i=0; i <  master.resultControl.options.length; i++){ 
    master.resultControl.options[i] = null;
}
//***************************************************************

var handler=master.addControl.getAttribute("onbeforeadd");
    if (handler !=null && handler !="")
    {
        if (!eval(handler+"(master)"))
            return;
    }
    var needToAdjustResultBox=false;
    if (master.resultControl.offsetWidth < master.candidateControl.offsetWidth)
    {
        needToAdjustResultBox=true;
    }
    var dirty=false;
    var pos=-1;
    for (var i=0; i < master.candidateControl.options.length; i++)
    {
        if (master.candidateControl.options[i].selected)
        {
            if (!dirty)
                pos=master.resultControl.length;
            master.resultControl.options[master.resultControl.length]=              GipNewOption(
                    master.candidateControl.options[i].text,
                    master.candidateControl.options[i].value);
            // HACK **********************************************************  
            // never remove items from the candidate box (the one on the left)
            //master.candidateControl.options[i]=null;
            dirty=true;
            // as we don't remove anything anymore, no need to decrement
            //i--;
            // ***************************************************************
        }
    }
    if (dirty)
    {
        GipSetHiddenControlValue(master);
        if (pos >=0)
        {
            master.resultControl.options[pos].selected=true;
            GipSelectResultItems(master)
        }
    }
    handler=master.addControl.getAttribute("onafteradd");
    if (handler !=null && handler !="")
    {
        eval(handler+"(master)");
    }
}
```

Comment: This can by bypassed by holding shift when selecting. Is there a better solution?